# expanding frame inside canvas with scrollbar to full window width tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to the first section in red and scrollbar, the entire width of the green frame. Then expanding the blue section the whole width of the blue section.
I am using a frame embedded in a canvas to have get that scrollbar, so it complicates the whole process. My code for this looks as follows:

```
        self.invest_frame = Frame(root)
        root.config(background='green')
        self.invest_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2,columnspan=1, sticky='news')
        #root.columnconfigure(1, weight=0)

        self.invest_frame.config(background='blue')
        self.invest_frame.columnconfigure(1,weight=432)

        self.main_canvas = Canvas(self.invest_frame)
        self.main_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.main_canvas.config(background='red')


        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.invest_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.main_canvas.yview)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill = Y,anchor=W)

        self.main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.main_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.main_canvas.bbox('all')))

        self.main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.main_canvas.bbox("all"))

        self.second_frame = Frame(self.main_canvas)
        self.main_canvas.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.second_frame.config(background='blue')

        self.main_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.second_frame, anchor='nw')
```

I tried throwing around some column configures to expand it, but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: We would like to help, but your question does not provide a [complete, minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide the complete code, with correct syntax, so that we can reproduce your problem. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the canvas and scrollbar are children of `self.invest_frame`, you need to use

```py
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

to expand `self.invest_frame` to fill available space (green region) horizontally.

To expand the `blue` frame to fill the canvas width, you need to change the width of `self.second_frame` to the width of `self.main_canvas` using `self.main_canvas.itemconfigure()` whenever the size of the canvas is changed:

```py
# save the item ID
self.second_frame_id = self.main_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.second_frame, anchor='nw')
# expand self.second_frame to fill canvas width
self.main_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.main_canvas.itemconfigure(self.second_frame_id, width=e.width))
```

Also note that the following line:

```py
self.main_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.main_canvas.bbox('all')))
```

should be changed to

```py
self.second_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.main_canvas.bbox('all')))
```